# Firing events with Measurement Protocol to specific Analytics account does not work

Tags: google-analytics

We've been working on tracking events with Google Measurement Protocol for multiple sites. For several sites this works but for 1 site the events do not show up in the Events section in GA.

So we then used Google Hitbuilder to verify the trackingcodes we sent. Even with Hitbuilder the events do not show up in 1 property while they show up in another.

Does anybody have any ideas what could cause this?

Regards,

Vincent

Comment: Did you check the filters in the views of our property ? If the hits show up in one property but not the other this seems to be the most likely culprit.

Comment: Check the property ID, filters in the view etc. Might be the IP is excluded.